# Where does chrome developer tools show the real calculated width of an element

Tags: css, width, margin, padding

I've read somewhere on the internet on the box model and it says that the `real width` of a block element is not it's width as defined in the CSS but calculated according to the below formula:

> Real Width = margin-right + border-right + padding-right + width +
>   padding-left + border-left + margin-left

So this `Real Width` that we talk about- is this also a value that is computed by the browser and shown as a css property that can be inspected - or is it only a term that web-designers use to plan their layouts accordingly.

For example I created a div and specified it's width to be 300px, set it's margin and padding to 10px - Can I now go to the Chrome developer tools and find this `Real width` to be 340px??

Comment: Read this: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the width or height in CSS of, say, a div or p element, by default they set the width/height of the content inside the element. So you have to remember to mentally add on the padding, border thickness, and margin to see how far the box will extend.

But there is an alternative way to work, because CSS has a box-sizing property. If you set:

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

in the CSS, now any divs (or whatever element or selectors you specify) will include the padding and border in the width and height of the divs. It can be an easier way to work, especially on very complex pages with lots of stuff on them.

Note that it still does not include the margins in the width and height of the box, but you would not really want that anyway, as the margin is not really part of the box itself, just the sparation between the box and other stuff.

The box-sizing property works in all main current browser versions, and in IE from v8 on.

In Chrome, and most other browsers, if you press the F12 key it will divide the window into two parts, and show a developer tool for you. Click on the search icon in the top left of that window pane, then click on any part of the website page in the other half of the screen, and it will show all the CSS settings for the element you clicked on. You will also see a set of nested coloured boxes which show in diagram form all the width, padding, border and margin sizes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is amazingly helpful. another think that I wanted to know about is that the css-3 property box-sizing can have 3 permissible value: border-box, padding-box and content-box.
when I try to use border-box > It works as expected. But when I use padding-box - it shows up as an invalid property value in the developers console.. Is padding box not supported in chrome?

Comment: When box-sizing first came in Firefox was the only one to support the box-padding value. I don't know the state of affairs now but from what you say Chrome still doesn't, and probably some of the others as well, so best not to use that one. Content-box and border-box is the usual choice of values people use. I'm glad you found the above helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image: click on style then computed]

firsts go to developer console

then click style

then click computed

Comment: okay, and for the above example (div of width 300px, margin and padding of 10px)- which property in the computed section will be 340px. Do I need to check the "Show inherited properties" checkbox??

Comment: Guess one just has to always do the maths

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to clear about margin and padding ..

Margin not included into width because it not change size of any element.
so , If you create element with  300px width and set margin and padding of 10px
then It will  be

```
      300px Width + 10px leftmargin +10px right margin = 320px
```